# IE 10 adding pixels to inline-block list

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am making a taskbar for a fixed width site.  It has links set up as a list of inline blocks.  It is all sized in pixels and fits perfectly with FF, Opera, Safari, and Chrome.  On IE10 it puts the last link on a new line.

If I shorten it by several pixels, the IE10 will look good, but the other 4 Browsers will stop just short of the website's width.  I figure IE is adding pixels somewhere, but I can't figure out how to get rid of them.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="fixed">
        <ul>
            <li class="taskbar" id="first"><a href="index.php">ALL</a>
            </li><li class="taskbar"><a href="index.php">GEOGRAPHY</a>
            </li><li class="taskbar"><a href="index.php">SCIENCE</a>
            </li><li class="taskbar"><a href="index.php">ARTS</a>
            </li><li class="taskbar"><a href="index.php">HISTORY</a>
            </li><li class="taskbar"><a href="index.php">SPORTS</a>
            </li><li class="taskbar" id="last"><a href="index.php">MISC.</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Older Browsers */
    background: -prefix-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF);
    /* IE10 */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF);
    /* Opera */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, 0%, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome) */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF);
    /* Proposed W3C Markup */
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF 100%);
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #FFEE88 72px, #FFFFFF);*/
}

/* fixed width main body div */
.fixed {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFEE66;
}
.fixed ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.taskbar {
    display: inline-block;
}
.taskbar:hover {
    background-color: #FFFF99;
}
.taskbar a {
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 20px;
    background-image: url("images/taskbar_arrow.png");
    background-size: 18px 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #FFCC55;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#first a {
    border-left: 2px solid #FFCC55;
    padding-left: 19px;
}
```

Here is the requested Fiddle and I normalized CSS.  The colors are a bit messed up on the Fiddle for some reason, but the "Misc." goes to the next acting like IE10.

http://jsfiddle.net/2aa5n/3/

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Please use a `reset.css` or `normalize.css`.

Comment: Are you using a reset css or normalize.css? Are you using the `box-sizing:border-box` property?

Comment: setting it to normalize.css fixed the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this a few times. I don't have a solid answer right now, but I have a guess. You are not defining an actual width value for any of your navigation elements so the actual rendered size of the text comes into play. Since IE is native to Windows I *think* it takes advantage more of the graphics/true type font system and renders a more accurate font. I believe I have read where fonts are crisper in IE because of this.

That leaves you, I and others with a situation on our hands. First, should we continue to leave our navigation more flexible like this, or do we define actual width more?

Is this isolated to IE? Probably not, I am betting you will find similar issues on other platforms; MAC, iOS, Linux etc.

I thin I have opted for actually defining the widths myself. I think it is a safer bet.

Think about it this way, you have 3 font families defined in your CSS. If the platform does not have the first it goes to the 2nd, then the 3rd, then the default platform font. What does you nav look like in that situation? Each font has its own sizing, kerning, etc. So be master of your domain I think wins out here.